# Is it possible to convert enums to text in PostgreSQL

Tags: enumeration, sql-like, postgresql-9.3

Is is possible to convert an enum declared in a postgresql schema to text so that I could use like clause for the enum column?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can cast the enum into `text` easily and use any textual operators on it.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE enumfield::TEXT LIKE 'Some%';
```

There might be a better way to handle what you want to achieve since the performance of this isn't the best.