# SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input value for enum tableName.date_unit: ""

Tags: postgresql, go

I got this error when I try to get the list of all rows on my table. This only happens because I include one of the column in the `SELECT`. The column itself is an enum column and I wanna use `COALESCE` for the column in case it meets a null value.

This is a simplication of my code

```sql
SELECT id,
    user_id,
    coalesce(date_unit, '') date_unit
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = $1
```

I got this error when I try to run it

```bash
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input value for enum table_name.date_unit: ""
```

This is the error when I run it using SQLX On Golang

```bash
Pq: invalid input value for enum table_name.date_unit: \"\"
```

`date_unit` itself is an enum which has restricted values. It only accepts `day` and `month` as value in the table. But lots of rows have `null` value in `date_unit`.

I wanna convert it to `""` or empty string if `date_unit` value is `null`.

Is there a problem with the `COALESCE` with enum values? How should I use `COALESCE` to work with what I wanna do?

Comment: I think, `''` (a string) does not match the type of the column `date_unit`, so you probably need to type-convert `date_unit` _in_ the call to `coalesce` to string first.

Comment: @kostix how should I do that?

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(date_unit::text, '') ...`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280096/720999), but @mkopriva beat me to this :-)

Comment: To understand the underlying issue, consider that in the typical data model of a classic SQL-enabled database each column has a type; the type effectively limits the set of possible values a column may have in a row. But if a column is nullable, `NULL` is sort of a single extra value with peculiar properties, but it still has the type assigned to the column. In your example, the `date_unit` column in a row can have three values, one of which is `NULL`, but they all are of the same enum type, and you cannot `COALESCE` them to a value of another (a string).

Comment: Thanks @kostix & @mkopriva! I get it now, just tried your solutions and it wokrs!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in the comment section of the question.

To officiate it, as `date_unit` is not a `string` type, it cannot be returned when querying (invalid data type). As such, when querying, we should convert `date_unit` to string type.

This can be done using the query:

```
SELECT id,
    user_id,
    COALESCE(date_unit::text, '')
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = $1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
    user_id,
    coalesce(date_unit, '')
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = $1
```